# How can I use a different location, other than my C drive, to store my programs and desktop?

Tags: operating-systems, storage

I got a SSD which has enough room to run my OP and install my drivers. I want to know how to put C:\Users......\Desktop in a new location like D:\Desktop. 
I also want to do the same with Programs and Programs86

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use a [NTFS Junction Point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_junction_point) for moving a folder to a different drive.  It is not recommended to do this with system folders but if you have something like Steam which uses a lot of disk space then you can move the "steamapps" folder to a different drive and create a junction point for that.  Junction points are transparent to the operating system.  They look just like the original folder as far as Windows is concerned.  Junction points are available on Windows Vista and newer.

Comment: And in the case of Steam, make sure it is not running while you move the folder and create the junction.  Start it after doing the junction and Steam will not even know it happened, the files will just be on the other drive.

Comment: Also, if you are using Windows 8: [Don't](http://www.zdnet.com/dont-move-your-windows-user-profiles-folder-to-another-drive-7000022142) move your profile folders to another drive.

Answer (score 1):

Install programs using the custom install option for ones you DO NOT want on the SSD.  If have already installed he programs, uninstall them and reinstall.  During the install, find the path option and change C: to D: (if that is the appropriate drive letter).

You can move the desktop by right clicking on it in windows explorer under the user in the left pane and selecting properties; then select the "location" tab and type in a new location.  Again, you can simply change C: to D:.  You can do this with all the user folders; especially my documents, music, videos, downloads,and pictures.

As a note, you want as many programs as you can get on the SSD.  So remove or move the page file, hibernation files, system restore, temporary internet files, and all other non-program files from the ssd via remapping, moving, or moving with junction points.

Then run CCleaner and all aspects of windows drive cleaner to clean temporary files all past system restore points.

I have a Windows 7 install that uses about 40 GB with many larger programs installed.  If you have a 60GB or greater ssd, you should be able to fit windows and most of your programs on it with ease after moving all the non-program files.

Answer (score 0):

You can install programs anywhere you please, `C:/Program Files` is simply the default. So you can certainly use a second hard drive to install there. I have the exact same setup as you. Only the programs that I need to run speedily are installed on my SSD, while all of my games and other large programs are installed to my second drive.

The only issue you would ever run into is a poorly designed application that won't run correctly if not installed to the default Program Files directory, but such instances are likely rare.

You can **change** the default installation directory in Windows from `C:\Program Files` to something else by editing the following registry key thusly:

> 1. Start Registry Editor by entering “Regedit” in the search All programs.
> 2. Locate the following:
>    `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion`
> 3. Right click on the value named `ProgramFilesDir` & change the default value C:\Program Files to the path you want to install all your programs in.
> 4. Click OK and Exit.
>
> [Source](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_programs/how-do-you-change-the-default-installation/73450b25-d794-4f18-9add-75253b893343)

---

As for the Desktop, that can't really be moved **easily**. You can modify the [`ProfilesDirectory`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc722177%28WS.10%29.aspx) variable to point to a different location than `C:/Users`, but that would move all the profiles, not just one profile's desktop. Also, Microsoft only recommends "that you do this is a test environment".

A simpler option would be to create a directory on your second drive, then create shortcuts (either manually or through an automated means like a batch script or the like) for all the files in that folder.

---

### Alternative Solution

If you'd be okay with having one large volume to work with, you can [use a Spanned Volume](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772180.aspx) to use both drives as one volume, essentially combining their available disk space into your C: drive.

The downside to this would be a performance loss. Any data stored on the HDD would have a slower transfer rate than the SSD, and you wouldn't have much control over where Windows decides to place data.